# workflow with git and github with live website and development website

Tags: git, github

I have a live website that I want to use git/github.  The website has a local.config with database config and passwords, lots of user dirs, a cache dir and a database and I want to know how to best use git/gihub.  The first step is to move my live website into github.  Once I have moved it to github, I plan to clone it on a development server.  From the development server push updates to github and then ultimately to my live website.

How can I commit all files to github without including the passwords in local.config?  Also, how can I keep local.config files on the live web-server, gihub and a development server without overwriting them when I commit a change from a development server?

For the user dirs, I want to ignore all the individual user dirs AND the contents, however, I want to keep the main dir webroot/userdir (user dirs would go under webroot/userdir.  For my cache dir, I want to ensure no cache is githubbed but I want the dir 'cache' to remain.

I am so worried also about deleting the live website or portions of it when I update it from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudassir Razvi is correct that you can use gitignore to stop tracking your local.config file.  However, I typically find this to be bad practice (especially if you are creating an application for others to use such as with an open source project).  I prefer to continue tracking changes to the local.config file so that you may still add new config variables moving forward.  Once the website is cloned on the webserver, you can simply stop tracking changes to your config file on the live server.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged "config.local"
```

This has the same effect as adding it to the gitignore file, with the exception that it can add a little security by helping to hide your sensitive file.  This is particularly useful if your gitignore file is web accessible.

More importantly though, this prevents accidental updates if you mistakenly change or remove your gitignore file and it also allows your other clones to continue tracking changes since gitignore files are cloned as well.

You can resume tracking any time with this command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged "config.local"
```

Also helpful, you can list which files are assume-unchanged at any time.

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your local.config file to gitignore before committing it. But have a copy of it wherever you want. Git will not touch the files that you choose to ignore.

In short whatever you don't want to be githubbed is to be added to gitignore/exclude. But this will mean that you are not version controlling those files.

Hope this answers the question!

Happy gitting!